# is there a way to access LXC containers from web by using there own ip?

Tags: amazon-ec2, lxc, lxd

so basically i have installed LXD / LXC on Ubuntu host running on EC2 instance 
my final goal would be to access the LXC online (webserver) with it's own static public ip i can access the host public ip but not the lxc containers

- i have created a container and installed Apache on both the host and the container

Comment: is this still active? I will answer if you still need it.

Comment: thanks a lot yeah in fact i do need it , and after extensive googling i don't see the answer to this anywhere online so really appreciate your answer

Comment: Hmm... Hold on. Are you trying to give the lxc container its own external ip? In this case, I can't help. Sorry. I can help with a) exposing a port or b) makings the ec2 instance's external ip refer to the lxc container.

Comment: yeah thanks , but i do have access to this information , but won't help with my type of application again thinks for spending time looking into this .